non-normal subgroups of a finite $p$-group
throughout studying a paper about finite $p$-groups,
I have a question as follows,
Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian $p$-group, where $p$ is odd and $Z(G)$ is cyclic.
($Z(G)$ denotes the center of $G$). Also let $d$ be the derived length of $G$,
where $d\geq 3$ and assume that $G^{(d-1)}$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$.
Since $G$ is non-abelian, $G^{\prime}\leq \Phi(G)$ and ${\mbox rank} (G/\Phi(G))\geq 2$,
there exists a basis $B$ for ${\bar G}:=G/\Phi(G)$ and elements ${\bar y_0}, {\bar y_1}$  in $B$ (especially $y_0, y_1\in G\setminus G^{\prime}$)
such that $\langle y_0\rangle\ntriangleleft G$ and
$\langle y_1\rangle\ntriangleleft G$.
Also since $d\geq 3$, similarly we could show that
there exists $x\in G^{\prime}\setminus G^{\prime\prime}$ such
that $\langle x\rangle\ntriangleleft G$.
Question: Are these true that $\langle y_0y_1\rangle\ntriangleleft G$,
$\langle y_0x\rangle\ntriangleleft G$ and $\langle y_1x\rangle\ntriangleleft G$?
Many thanks!

@ Arturo Magidin sorry! I forgot  the condition "minimal", which I added it. Thank you .

Again, I suspect there are conditions that you are impkicitly assuming but not telling us. For instance, are you assuming that $\langle y_0\rangle \neq \langle y_1\rangle$? Right now, nothing stops $y_0=y_1^{-1}$, which of course would make $y_0y_1=e$. Even then, I suspect you could take a central element $z$ so that $y_0z$ is not a power of $y_0$, and then take $y_1=(y_0z)^{-1}$.

@ Arturo Magidin,  Actually I choose $y_0$ and $y_1$ modulo $\Phi(G)$, form a basis of $G/\Phi(G)$. I added these details to the question. Hopefully now there is no ambiguous. Many thanks for your accuracy and your time on the question.
